# Check signature of an apk

Tags: android, apk

I want to read signatures of an .apk file that is locally stored on a device. I use.

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageArchiveInfo(apkFilePath, PackageManager.GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES)
```

It returns packageInfo but always with null signingInfo field.

How to get signing info for apk file?

Comment: I've faced the same issue and didn't find any solution either. My current workaround is to use the deprecated `PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Not a real solution but it seems to be fixed in Android 11 / 12.

On my Android 11 and 12 emulators, packageInfo.signingInfo is not null.

But on my Android 9 and 10 emulators, packageInfo.signingInfo is null.

So I'm using GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES only when SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).